# Creating a simple web app based on a statistical model prediction formula

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I work as a biostatistician and I've recently had a very specific idea which relies heavily on web development, a field in which I have no experience at all, and so I'd like to get some general advice on how should I proceed.

In order not to complicate things too much, let's suppose that my statistical model is based on the following formula: probability = exp(height*1.5 + BMI*2). What I want is to create a web page where the user can input a height value and a BMI value and get the result of that equation (that is, the probability), just that. Of course the actual formula is more complex, but math is not the hurdle here, the "web architecture" side is the problem.

I *know* that it must be a trivial problem but I have no idea on where to start. What is the simplest way to accomplish this? Should I use a JavaScript framework like React or is this overkill? Could you point me to some kind of template or tutorial which covers something similar to this? I've already done some research but I'm pretty lost. I'd like it to work both offline (as an HTML + whatever else is needed that you can execute from a local folder) and online.

I regularly work with R so I think I'd be able to learn any specifics related to the code, the problem as I said is that this field is so vast to me that I don't even know where to start.

[Here's a mockup of what I mean in case it helps. Please don't laugh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er5xG.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is going to be hard to recommend a full stack based on what you have provided. You may benefit from a introductory web development course. However, I think exploring a couple of code playgrounds and existing examples will help you refine your demo example. Something like the following https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue.

Comment: what you have done ?